# Uploading image to s3 bucket returns InvalidAccessKeyId error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am having a problem when uploading to a s3 bucket. My app is written in nodeJS, running in an ec2 instance. When I upload an image from my nodeJS  I get this error

> "error": "Error -> InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

But it works perfectly when I run it on my localhost. I do not get any no InvalidAccessKeyId error.

The error only shows when I run it in production(ec2 instance).

Comment: It looks like the app in the aws instance does not get the key and it it probably empty.

Comment: my key is set in node js, not by passing from laravel to node js

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Perhaps you could clarify your question, esp. "my code" and what apps are running, where they are running and what they are doing.

Comment: I already edited my question hope you get it this time, thanks in advance sir

Comment: Thanks. How do you pass the key to the node app?

Comment: my AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is already set im my node js i ddnt pass it from laravel to node js.

Comment: They are defined as constants?

Comment: yes I already set everything in node js

Comment: Could you show the code, where those values are set and the provide the filename?

Comment: const env = {
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY: '',
 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '',
 REGION : '',
 Bucket: ''
};

module.exports = env;

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: s3.env.js file i use this https://grokonez.com/aws/node-js-restapis-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-using-express-multer-aws-sdk btw

Comment: What other files are in the folder `app/config/`?

Comment: config/
        ./multer.config.js
        ./s3.config.js
        ./s3.env.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188285/discussion-between-mbuechmann-and-ampedo).